# javascript-hovering one element changes other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want that hovering one element affects other element. In this I want on hovering some `div` part creates animation in images in other `div`. For that I used this code:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="s">hover here</div>
<section>
  <div class="hs-wrapper">
    <img src="images/1.gif" alt="image01"/>
    <img src="images/2.gif" alt="image02"/>
  </div>
</section>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".s").mouseenter(function () {
          $(".hs-wrapper img").css({
        -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
       -moz-animation-play-state: running;
        -o-animation-play-state: running;
         -ms-animation-play-state: running;
         animation-play-state: running; 
        });
      $(".s").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".hs-wrapper img").css({
        -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
         -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
          -o-animation-play-state: paused;
          -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
           animation-play-state: paused;    
         });
       });
```

But it's not working. Please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the markup you provided, you *don't* need jQuery for this.

Just use the selector `.s:hover + section .hs-wrapper img`. Using the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/adjacent), you can select the succeeding `section` element when hovering over `.s`. From there, the child `img` element is selected.

```
section .hs-wrapper img {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
}
.s:hover + section .hs-wrapper img {
    -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -o-animation-play-state: running;
    -ms-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
```

Here is a [**basic example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5tzm31ad/):

```
section .hs-wrapper img {
    opacity:0;
    transition: 3s ease-out; /* Mouseleave */
}
.s:hover + section .hs-wrapper img {
    opacity:1;
    transition: .5s ease; /* Mouseenter */
}
```